# Pointer a Class C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, struct, typedef

I just wanted to know if I can point to class using this implementation:

```
class hello
{
    public:
         void blah();
};

typedef hello* pointer_to_class_hello;

pointer_to_class _hello p1;
```

So now, does this new pointer p1 point to the class "hello"?

Comment: You can't "point to a class", you can point to _instances_ of a class.

Comment: Yes it would, if you removed the space in your last line before "_hello"

Comment: It would be more correct to say that a variable of type `pointer_to_class_hello` (such as `p1`) points to an *instance* of the `hello` class.

Comment: what do you mean by point to an instance of a class?

Comment: Think of a class as a blueprint for an object. It describes it's attributes and capabilities. An instance of a class (i.e. an object) is an entity built from that blueprint. Given a single class, you can have any number of instances, and it is these instances that pointers point to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class hello
{
    public:
         void blah();
};

typedef hello* pointer_to_class_hello;

pointer_to_class_hello p1;
```

Does this new pointer p1 point to the class "hello"? No, pointers in C++ point to objects (a class is a type), be it with automatic, static or dynamic storage duration (or to functions). Besides that, `p1` is uninitialized, so it doesn't yet point to any valid location.

```
hello H;
p1 = &H;  // Now it does, it points to H.
```

Comment: An unitialized pointer does not point "nowhere". It always points somewhere, you just don't know where.

Comment: @Dima, Yes, I agree. Better now?

Comment: @jrok, almost. You should also mention that using an uninitialized pointer will at best result in a crash, and at worst in unpredictable behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Class `hello` is a *type*.

`pointer_to_class_hello` is a *type* that is synonymous with `hello*` (which is a *type* of pointer to an *instance* of *type* `hello`):

```
typedef hello* pointer_to_class_hello;
```

`p1` is declared to be a *variable* of *type* `pointer_to_class_hello`:

```
pointer_to_class_hello p1; // note extra space removed in type of p1
```

At this point `p1` does not point to anything, in fact it's value is most likely "garbage" (think of it as a random number).  You need to assign a valid *value* to it before you can use it.  To do so, you need an *instance* (also called an *object*) of class `hello`, like this:

```
hello h;
```

Then you can assign the *address* of this *instance* to `p1`:

```
p1 = &h; // & returns the address where h resides in memory
```

Alternatively, you can do the assignment at the point of declaration as well:

```
pointer_to_class_hello p1 = &h;
```

Then you can use the pointer to access the object pointed to:

```
p1->blah(); // at this point this is same as h.blah();
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to understand the difference between a class and an instance, aka object. An object is a variable and the class is its type.

So a pointer cannot point to the class.  It can only point to an object.  More specifically, a pointer is the address of the memory location where the object is stored.

However, you do often hear "pointer to class A".  That refers to the type of the pointer.
For example if you see `int *a`, you can say "`a` is a pointer to integer", meaning that that is the type of variable `a`.  However, `a` does not point to the type `int`, it points to a particular integer.

By the same token `p1` in your example has the type "pointer to class `hello`".  However it can only point to an object of `class hello`, because it makes no sense to point to the class.

Note one important thing, though. The way you have it declared, `p1` is not initialized.  That does not mean that it is NULL or that it points "nowhere".  It means it points to some arbitrary memory location.  If you try to use it, the behavior of the program is unpredictable.  If you are lucky, you will get a segmentation fault, meaning your program will crash.  Generally, when you declare a pointer, you should make it point to something as soon as possible.  You might have something like this:

```
// make p1 point to a dynamically allocated object
pointer_to_class _hello p1 = new hello;
```

or

```
// make p1 point to a local variable
hello objectOfClassHello;
pointer_to_class _hello p1 = &objectOfClassHello;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a pointer to a class; only a pointer to the address of an object or function.

```
hello myHello;                        // Declare a variable of type class hello
pointer_to_class_hello p1 = &myHello; // Point to the address of the variable
```

Comment: The pointer contains the address, not points to it (at least in the OP's code)  Also, `myHello` is an object, cannot assign pointer returned by `new`

Comment: Shouldn't it be "hello *myHello = new hello()"? Or just "hello myHello()".

Comment: Yes ... too much Java lately; fixed.  Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

It should be this:

```
pointer_to_class_hello p1;
```

You have an extra space there for some unknown reason.